# webkit framework missing in lion

Tags: xcode4, webkit, osx-lion

I am trying to add webkit framework to Xcode,
steps I followed is

selected the target,
went to the 'build phases' tab,
opened the 'Link binary with Libraries'
Use the + to add the library

But in MacOSX 10.7(Lion),I was not able to see webkit.framework in the framework list.

Any Ideas Where it resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using Xcode 4.3.2 on Lion and my webkit framework appears to be in place, check the following directory to make sure your framework hasn't one way or another been deleted. If it isn't at this path, you may need to reinstall Xcode.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I upgraded from Snowleopard to Lion.

I had to install the new version of Xcode (4.3) with the IosSDK.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,My current OS version is 10.7.3 and Xcode version is 4.3.2.